# Re-use socket multiple times for sending and receiving strings/bytes between C++ and Java

Tags: java, c++, sockets, bufferedreader

I am trying to reuse the same socket to send and receive strings (and/or bytes) between a C++ Client and a Java Server (or vice versa). I am able to reuse a socket in the sense that I can send (once) from Java and receive (once) from C++ and do the same the other way around (send from C++ to Java). However, if I try to send to Java from C++ more than once, the second (String or byte) won't come. For the case of a String (Sending an array of char from C++), I always get a null back. Note that I don't have this issue while communicating between C++ and C++ or Java and Java with the same code. I am aware that BufferedInputReader needs a new line. For bytes, I get IndexOutOfBound. See below code. Java Server-->

```
 // in main...
    TCP tcp = new TCP();
    tcp.sendStr("Send File");
    String x = tcp.recvStr();
    System.out.println(x);
    x = tcp.recvStr();
    System.out.println(x);
    //issue starts from here
    x = tcp.recvStr();
    System.out.println(x);

 //.... IN TCP CLASS
 // Global class variables in TCP
 ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8080); 
 serverSocket.accept(); // this is done somewhere in the class
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
 PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

    public String recvStr(){

    String msg = null;

    try {
        msg = br.readLine(); 
    }


    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return msg;
   }

public void sendStr (String msg) {

    try {

        pw.write(msg);
        pw.flush();   
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

C++ Client Code

```
 //.. main thread of execution
 struct sockaddr_in server_address, client_addr;
 memset(&server_address, '0', sizeof(server_address));
 server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
 server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
 server_address.sin_port = htons(PORT);
 TCP tcp;
 char receiveBuffer[1024] = {};

 int server_fd = 0,  new_socket = 0;

tcp.RecieveChar(server_address, receiveBuffer, new_socket);

std::cout << receiveBuffer << std::endl;

char chunkSize[64] = "yeahh!\n";

tcp.SendChar(server_address, chunkSize, new_socket, server_fd);

char chunk[128] = "weeeee\n";

tcp.SendChar(server_address, chunk, new_socket, server_fd);

//... in class tcp

template<int SIZE>
void TCP::SendChar(struct sockaddr_in server_addr, const char (&data)[SIZE], int &socket_id, bool close_connection ){

    int opt = 1;
    int addrlen = sizeof(server_addr);
    int server_accept;

    // Creating socket file descriptor
    // Create one if only one does not exist
    if(socket_id == 0){
        if ((socket_id = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == 0)
        {
            std::cerr << "Error in creating socket" << std::endl;
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        // Forcefully attaching socket to the port 8080
        if (setsockopt(socket_id, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT,
                                                      &opt, sizeof(opt)))
        {
            std::cerr << "Error in setting socket" << std::endl;
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        // Forcefully attaching socket to the port
        if (bind(socket_id, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr,
                                     sizeof(server_addr))<0)
        {
            std::cerr << "Error in binding socket" << std::endl;
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if (listen(socket_id, 3) < 0)
        {
            std::cerr << "Error in accepting listening" << std::endl;
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if ((server_accept = accept(socket_id, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr,
                                        (socklen_t*)&addrlen))<0)
        {
            std::cerr << "Error in accepting connection" << std::endl;
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        socket_id = server_accept;
    }


    sendto(socket_id, data, SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr*) &server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)); // need to change to client address?

}

void TCP::RecieveChar(struct sockaddr_in server_addr, char *received_data,
    int &socket_address_binder, bool close_connection){
    int valread;

    if(socket_address_binder == 0){
        if ((socket_address_binder = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
        {
            std::cerr << "\n Socket creation error" << std::endl;
        }

        if (connect(socket_address_binder, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) < 0)
        {
            std::cerr << "\nConnection Failed \n" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    valread = read( socket_address_binder , received_data, 1024);

    if(valread == 0){
        std::cerr << "Error in read" << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "Received: " << received_data << std::endl;
}
```

Note that I've included code for sending and receiving array of chars/String. I can also send a file between the two without an issue, however when I try to reuse the socket after having received a String in Java, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:128)
```

Comment: Are you using multiple threads?  Does the problem go away if you make `sendStr` a `synchronized` method?

Comment: Not using multiple threads, one thread of execution

Comment: @VGR : See my answer, I figured out what the issue was, however you can still help in understanding why.

Answer (score -1):

I figured out what is causing the issue, however I don't know why this causes an issue. The issue is because I am using C char arrays, and the char array appends a null char at the end of the array. Once BufferedReader receives Null from the stream, it just sees everything else as null. I don't know why it behaves this way. I found a fix for it that't to read the input one char at a time, once I see the null character (which is 0 ASCII), I stop. The try clause inside recvStr() method can be replaced with the following:

```
    try {
        int a = -1;
            while(true){
                a = br.read();
                if(a == 0)
                    break;
                message = message + (char)a;
            }

    }
```

Comment: Not so. When `BufferedReader` *returns* -1, meaning end of stream, it will *of course* keep doing so. It does not behave as you describe on a null byte. And you should not be transmitting trailing nulls in the first place.

Comment: Also I'm not transmitting null bytes because I want to, sending the a C char array contains a null ending.